# Lucene BlockJoin query to match when all terms appear in either parent or child docs

Tags: lucene

I have populated an index with parent and child docs, using "Blocks".  i.e. docs are added using the IndexWriter.addAll() method, with the last doc being the parent doc.

At the moment, I've only succeeded in searching for 'Blocks' whereby *any* terms in the query appear in either a parent or it's children.  This is giving me skewwed results.  e.g. I'm getting top results where just one of the terms appears many times in a 'Block', but other terms don't appear at all.

I want to search for 'Blocks' whereby *all* terms in the query must appear in either a parent or it's children.

But I'm not sure how to construct the query.

My current query code is as follows:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer();
//Note, both parent and child docs have a 'textContent' field
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("textContent", analyzer);
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("${indexParentDir}/${name}.lucene"));
BitSetProducer parentsFilter = new QueryBitSetProducer(new TermQuery(new Term("child", "N")));

Query textQuery = queryParser.parse("foo bar");

//Construct child query
BooleanQuery.Builder childQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
childQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(textQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
childQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("child", "Y")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
Query childQuery = new ToParentBlockJoinQuery(childQueryBuilder.build(), parentsFilter, ScoreMode.Avg);

//Construct parent query
BooleanQuery.Builder parentQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
parentQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(textQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
parentQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("child", "N")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));

//Construct join of child and parent query
BooleanQuery.Builder childAndParentQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
childAndParentQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(childQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
childAndParentQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(parentQueryBuilder.build(), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
Query childAndParentQuery = childAndParentQueryBuilder.build();

//Run the query
DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
CheckJoinIndex.check(reader, parentsFilter);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
searcher.search(childAndParentQuery, 10);
```

The above code will return top results whereby just one of the terms appears many times.  e.g. if 'foo' appears 100 times in either parent or child docs.  But 'bar' does not appear at all.

I would like to return only results whereby *all* terms (e.g. 'foo' and 'bar') appear in either a parent, or one of it's children.

One option would be to create a field in the Parent docs, which is an aggregation of all textContent fields in parent and child docs, and only search across the new aggregated field.  But these indexes are already quite large.  (e.g. 50GB).  And I am still required to keep the textContent seperated in parent and children for display purposes, so creating an aggregated field would almost double the size of the index.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by using a [DisjunctionMaxQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DisjunctionMaxQuery.html) instead of a BooleanQuery to join the parent and child queries together.

From the documentation:

> ...We want the primary score to be the one associated with the highest
>   boost, not the sum of the field scores (as BooleanQuery would give).
>   If the query is "albino elephant" this ensures that "albino" matching
>   one field and "elephant" matching another gets a higher score than
>   "albino" matching both fields...

Updated code:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer();

//Note, both parent and child docs have a 'textContent' field
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("textContent", analyzer);
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("${indexParentDir}/${name}.lucene"));
BitSetProducer parentsFilter = new QueryBitSetProducer(new TermQuery(new Term("child", "N")));

Query textQuery = queryParser.parse("foo bar");

//Construct child query
BooleanQuery.Builder childQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
childQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(textQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
childQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("child", "Y")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
Query childQuery = new ToParentBlockJoinQuery(childQueryBuilder.build(), parentsFilter, ScoreMode.Avg);

//Construct parent query
BooleanQuery.Builder parentQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
parentQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(textQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
parentQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("child", "N")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
Query parentQuery = parentQueryBuilder.build();

//Construct join of child and parent query
Query childAndParentQuery = new DisjunctionMaxQuery(Arrays.asList(childQuery, parentQuery), 0.5f);

//Run the query
DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
CheckJoinIndex.check(reader, parentsFilter);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
searcher.search(childAndParentQuery, 10);
```